7 for 5n+1 series diverges to infinity?
Write an odd integer in the "modified" binary form as $2^m - 1$ and apply 5n+1 (similar to applying the rules of original 3n + 1) to it:
\begin{align}
n &= 2^m - 1                     \\
\mathcal O1     &=  (2^2 + 1)(2^m - 1) + 1      \\
                &=  2^{m + 2} + 2^m - 2^2         \\
\mathcal E1     &=  2^{m} + 2^{m - 2} - 1    \\
\mathcal O2     &=  2^{m + 2} + 2^{m + 1} + 2^{m - 2} - 2^2   \\
\mathcal E2     &=  2^{m + 1} + 2^m + 2^{m - 3} - 2
\end{align}
where $\mathcal O$ and $\mathcal{E}$ are integers obtained at end of odd and even steps, respectively.
If we let $m = 3$, the integer obtained at $\mathcal{E}2$ becomes $2^4 + 2^3 - 1$.
That is, starting from $2^3 - 1$, we obtain the integer $2^4 + 2^3 - 1$.
It is seen that the integer $2^3 - 1$ reoccurs with a higher integer.
If we apply the rules of $5n + 1$ to $2^4 + 2^3 - 1$, the integer $2^3 - 1$ will reoccur with more higher powers.
So, can it be concluded that $2^3 - 1$ diverges? The value of $2^3 - 1$ is obviously 7. Can the same be assumed true for any odd integer for which the "modified" binary expression ends in $2^3 - 1$?

"Applying $5n+1$ to a number", what does that mean?

Applying 5n+1 means to carry out odd or even steps based on the integer.

Is this a modification to collatz ?

Yes, it is modified collatz cycle where 3 is replaced by 5. A lot of work has been done on modified collatz cycles as well

In plain English, are you saying that if $n$ is even it goes to $n/2$, and if $n$ is odd it goes to $5n+1$? And you're asking whether the sequence starting with $7$ diverges? The answer is, of course it diverges – BUT no one has been able to prove it, and looking at what happens after two steps of the iteration is not enough to conclude that you know what happens after that.

For what it's worth, the sequence is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A028389/b028389.txt and you might note that term number $136$ is $862777216$ while term $143$ is the much smaller number $6740447$.
